# Laser detector parts

Tags: laser, light-sensor

I have been trying to find laser level detector components.  I took apart one on hand, see what looks like basic photodiodes and a light tube.  Note the 3 photodiodes visible in the center part.

Could these be off the shelf photodiodes?

Any ideas how they are determining location?

Laser level type = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_level

[image: Light tube]
[image: End diode]
[image: End diode angle 2]
[image: Middle diode 1 of 3]

Comment: Ahh I need more info.  Is this to measure "level", as in perpendicular to gravity.  Or to measure the level of some (liquid) in a container?  (How about more on the part you've got pics of.)

Comment: Level, as in rotating laser beam from contractor laser level.

Comment: Looks like it simply compares the amount of light at each end. The rings on the rod scatter the incoming laser into the rod a bit. The two photodiodes see the flash, and the chip compares the amplitudes. Perhaps uses the LEDs under the tube for self calibration.

Comment: did you ever manage to make your own one? I have the same requirements and I am struggling to get an off the shelf component to make a unit to control up and down movement of an electric motor based on the change in heigh from the rotating laser beam hitting the receiver.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, @tomnexus gave me a clue... I think there is only one photodiode (PD) and as he said the rings scatter light that is not "on axis".  So you find a signal maximum when the laser light is perfectly aligned, (cute).

And to answer the question: Yes I think you can use a commercial PD.  You'll want the PD area to fill the end area of the rod... there might be some diffusor in the middle there between the PD and rod.